# geometrical calculations of calculus- primitive functions

Tags: calculus

A curve satisfies 
$$\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}=6,$$
and its tangent at $~(-1,3)~$ is perpendicular to the line 
$$2x+4y-3=0.$$
Find the equation of the curve.

I need help starting this question.

I'm not sure what I'm substituting and finding primitives of, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Integrate once
$$ y^{'}=6x+c_1 $$
Once again integrate
$$ y=3x^2 +c_1 x +c_2$$
Since it satisfies the given point
$$ x=1,\, y= 3, $$
we plug in the above to get
$$ c_1=c_2 = c \tag1$$
$$y = 3x^2 +c(x+1) \tag2$$

The parabola passes through $ (x,y)=(-1,3)$

Straight line equation considering negative reciprocal slope of $-\frac12=2$

Using this slope the equation of tangent line in point-slope form is:

$$ \frac{y-3}{x+1}=2 $$

or
$$ y-2x-5=0 \tag3 $$

Eliminate $y$ between 2) and 3) and simplify parabola equation

$$3x^2 +x(c-2)+(c-5)=0 \tag4$$

Tangency requires that the discriminant $\Delta$ of quadratic equation should vanish
$$ \Delta =(c+2)^2-4\cdot3\cdot(c-5)=0 \rightarrow c^2-16 c+64=0 \rightarrow (c-8)^2=0$$
$$ c= (8,8) \tag5 $$
a repeated root for tangency..

$$ y= 3x^2+ 8(x+1). \tag6$$

A graph drawn visually  confirms position of given point of tangency and also perpendicularity to the given line.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Constant curvature indicates that the curve is a parabola.

So, you may assume $y=3(x-a)^2+b$, automatically satisfying $y’’=6$.

Its tangent at $x=-1$ Is then $y’(-1)=-6(1+a)$ and is equal to 2, which allows $a$ to be found.

With $a$ known, $b$ can also be found with $y(-1)=3$.

In the end, it should come out as $y=3x^2+8x+8$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:**

$\dfrac{d^2 y}{dx^2}=6\implies\dfrac {dy}{dx}=6x+C_1\implies y=3x^2+C_1x+C_2.$

Use the following information to solve for $C_1$ and $C_2$:

when $x=-1, y=3$ and $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ is the negative reciprocal of the slope of the line 
$2x+4y-3=0.$